# How to download more than 100 of rows & columns with jspdf & jspdf-autotable in react datatable component?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a React Matetial UI Data Grid component & data with 100 of rows & columns. Then how to I download that data with JsPdf & JsPdf-Autotable ?

I download that data, but the columns are collapsed due to more than 15 number of columns. Then how to I download that data without any column breaking